# Какую связь нужно использовать

Tags: база-данных, erwin

Пытаюсь построить в ERwin модель базы данных по правилам БП:

```
1. Туры имеющие одинаковые название, но имеющие разные странны, cчитается разными турами.
2. Клиенты могут иметь более одного номера телефона. Клиенты не могут иметь одинаковые номера телефонов.
3. Отели имеющие одинаковые названия, но разные кол-во звезд, cчитается разными отелями.
4. За сотрудником закреплено только одно агенство. В агентстве работает много сотрудников.
5. Сотрудник может иметь только одну должность.
6. Клиент может иметь несколько виз.
8. Клиент может иметь только один паспорт. Номер паспорта уникален.
9. Зарплата сотрудника зависит от должности.
10. В продаже тура участвует только один сотрудник.
```

Получается что-то вроде этого,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] но я до сих пор не могу понять когда нужно использовать идентифицирующую связь, а когда неидентифицирующую. Почитав гугол я так до конца и не понял в чем между ними разница, и когда какую использовать